# Calendar in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, date, calendar, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create calendar table using this query (it works in common SQL)

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,t4 * 10000 + t3 * 1000 + t2 * 100 + t1 * 10 + t0,'1970-01-01') AS date_value
FROM
    (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
    (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
    (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
    (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
    (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
```

but when I migrate this to SparkSQL and do some modification (date_add function), it always failed and shows syntax error : missing ')' at 'SELECT'
Any help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT 10*t1.t1+t0.t0 id, DATE_ADD('1970-01-01', 10*t1.t1+t0.t0) AS date_value
FROM
    (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 t0 UNION SELECT 2 t0 UNION SELECT 3 t0 UNION SELECT 4 t0 UNION SELECT 5 t0 UNION SELECT 6 t0 UNION SELECT 7 t0 UNION SELECT 8 t0 UNION SELECT 9 t0) t0,
    (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 t1 UNION SELECT 2 t1 UNION SELECT 3 t1 UNION SELECT 4 t1 UNION SELECT 5 t1 UNION SELECT 6 t1 UNION SELECT 7 t1 UNION SELECT 8 t1 UNION SELECT 9 t1) t1
```

Result:

```
    +-----+-------------+--+
    | id  | date_value  |
    +-----+-------------+--+
    | 11  | 1970-01-12  |
    | 61  | 1970-03-03  |
    | 31  | 1970-02-01  |
    | 51  | 1970-02-21  |
    | 41  | 1970-02-11  |
    ...
    | 80  | 1970-03-22  |
    | 90  | 1970-04-01  |
    | 70  | 1970-03-12  |
    | 0   | 1970-01-01  |
    +-----+-------------+--+
```